# Video not playing inside <article> element

Tags: css, wordpress, youtube

I hope someone can point me in the right direction.
On my page, YouTube videos do not play directly on the blog page when you are in the "" element.

Here is the site: https://biog-biogas.com/blog/

If I drag them out of the  element in the inspector, or even if I click on the article I can play the videos normally.

I guess it's just a CSS problem? But I just can't figure it out. Already played around with z-index but unfortunately without success.

I am really grateful if someone could give me a tip.

Thanks and BR;
Niko

Comment: Please read [Something on my web site doesn't work. Can I just paste a link to it?](http://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/125997/something-on-my-web-site-doesnt-work-can-i-just-paste-a-link-to-it). Questions that depend on external resources to be understood become useless when the external resource goes away or is fixed. Create a [MCVE] and put it in **the question itself** instead.

Answer (score -1, accepted):

You have a restriction in pointer events in the css, remove it

Actual CSS

```
.post-entry-content {
  pointer-events: none;
}
```

Comment: Thanks a lot!! Sometimes it's easier then you thought. :) :)

Comment: I really do not understand why someone  gave me a negative, maybe is angry with is life.